# How to resize /run (to make /run/shm bigger) properly - and where is it's' size set?

Tags: mount

On Ubuntu 13.04 /dev/shm is symlink to /run/shm and /run/shm is just subdirectory of /run. /run is some tmpfs which is mounted but ………… I can't find by what and how (surely it is not present in /etc/fstab and I can't grep anything sensible in /etc/init*).

While usually this directory need no attention, both while trying to setup Oracle, and while trying to setup DB2, I faced errors which in the end turned out to mean „/dev/shm is too small”. Net is full of advice how to mount --rebind run to make it bigger, but this operation nicely breaks apps which use /run and are already running at the moment rebind happens (and there are a lot of them, especially on desktop, including things like upstart, networkmanager, or udev).

My questions:

1. Where exactly is the code which mounts /run, when does it happen?
2. What should I change to increase /run size at the moment it is created? (on my laptop it takes 10% of memory - 600MB on 6GB laptop - I'd like to give it 1GB)
3. If 2 is impossible, what is the proper moment to rebind /run to resize it - so it happens before anythning starts actually using /run?
4. Does there exist any documentation on the subject? While there are many posts and notes about /run as such, I couldn't find anything about configuring it.

Comment: For the sake of history: I found that best way to resolve oracle problems was to ... binary-edit $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle and change strings /dev/shm into /run/shm (fortunately they are of the same lenght). Oracle wrongly calculates size in case of symlink

Comment: @Mekk;  Brilliant !
Used:   "vi  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin# vi oracle"  then   "Shift-Colon"   then "%s/\/dev\/shm/\/run\/shm"  and ENTER.   Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ubuntu those mounts are configured in `/lib/init/fstab`, and as it says there in the default comments, to override the settings you can simply copy the line to `/etc/fstab` and modify as you see fit.

```
# /lib/init/fstab: static file system information.
#
# These are the filesystems that are always mounted on boot, you can
# override any of these by copying the appropriate line from this file into
# /etc/fstab and tweaking it as you see fit.  See fstab(5).
```

Comment: For me, despite having customized the size value of /run, it was still mounted using the 10% of physical memory default. When I type `mount`, the entry is listed with my updated value (in this case `50%`), but my actual allocated size for my /run directory is still `10%`. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @RyanGriffith, with the switch to systemd, /lib/init/fstab is gone, however systemd is supposed to still check /etc/fstab, and it worked for me when I tried it on 17.04.