# Ubuntu Server 14.04 run out of memory

Tags: 14.04, memory-usage

[image]

Attach is the screenshot of `htop` program. The memory usage always increase, but I could not find what program is *eating* my RAM. Afterwards, only 200MB memory left free :'(.

Could you give me some hints to fix this problem?

**Update**:

I stop all the processes I know (in fact there is only one process I ran), wait about 30 minutes and do

`free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15039      14687        352          0          1         16
-/+ buffers/cache:      14669        370
Swap:            0          0          0`

It seems to me that the memory free space will never come back.

**Update 2**

`ps aux --sort -rss | head
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1060  0.0  0.0 279756  3320 ?        Sl   15:11   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
ubuntu    1830  0.0  0.0  21808  3240 pts/1    Ss   15:12   0:00 -bash
root       751  0.0  0.0  10220  2296 ?        Ss   15:11   0:00 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
root      1054  0.0  0.0 344384  2264 ?        Ssl  15:11   0:00 NetworkManager
root         1  0.1  0.0  33760  2072 ?        Ss   15:11   0:03 /sbin/init
root      1327  0.0  0.0 287352  1712 ?        Sl   15:11   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
ubuntu   20475  0.0  0.0  17324  1424 pts/1    R+   15:48   0:00 ps aux --sort -rss
syslog     942  0.0  0.0 262132  1328 ?        Ssl  15:11   0:00 rsyslogd
root       530  0.0  0.0  51928  1268 ?        Ss   15:11   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon`

** Update 3: **

[Results of `sudo slabtop`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqwJN.png)

Comment: Maybe some useful pointers here http://superuser.com/questions/398862/linux-find-out-what-process-is-using-all-the-ram ?

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to check the processes with the largest RSS

```
ps aux --sort -rss | head
```

..or use tools such as slabtop to see where memory is being used on the Linux slab allocator:

```
sudo slabtop
```

Comment: I added the result of your command above. I do not find any process which consume a lot of CPU or RAM, but ``free -m`` still say that I have only about 300MB left

Comment: Yeah, I added the result of ``sudo slabtop`` too. It seems not understandable for me

Comment: There are a *lot* of kmalloc-32 slabs being used up there, I wonder if this is a memory leak in the kernel.

Comment: It seems there was a kernel bug with kmalloc-32:  https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2012/07/msg00619.html .  But that was back in 2012.  That can't still be in 14.04, could it?

Answer (score 1):

Your memory is probably being used as a RAM disk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).

Type `df -h`.  Do you see a "tmpfs" that is mounted on either `/dev/shm` or `/run/shm`? If so, that is your memory being used for that file system.

In the past, I have stored frequently accessed files there (Note:  the files are deleted when you reboot).  I don't remember the details about it, but it supposedly adjusts in size as you use memory.  However, I always wondered if I left a file there, whether it will never reclaim that space.  Thus, I gave up doing this.

If you search on this site for words like "RAM disk", `/dev/shm`, or `/run/shm` (the last one is the location used by older versions of Ubuntu), you will find more information.  See for example:

- [What are "/run/lock" and "/run/shm" used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for)
- [How to resize /run (to make /run/shm bigger) properly - and where is it's' size set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323066/how-to-resize-run-to-make-run-shm-bigger-properly-and-where-is-its-size)

Or this from another site:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html

(I hope this answers your question about where your memory went.  However, my suggestion is to leave it alone at its default size until you read up more about it.  I don't remember whether the system relies on it.)

Comment: Hello @Ray, thanks a lot. Actually I don't mind a lot, but when the memory is full, OOM Killer started to kill my applications :(

Comment: @kid_2901 Well, if the problem was OOM Killer, you probably should have said that in your original message.  Your original concern was the amount of RAM being used up, wasn't it?  If it's the OOM Killer, what error messages do you get when it kicks in, what are you running when it kicks in, etc.  Is it always the same program you're running, etc.  A single program can allocate a huge chunk of memory and use it up just when it's starting up.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this applies to Ubuntu but http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html gives some suggestions on guiding what it kills.