# How do I increase size of per-user tmpfs partition /run/user/$(id)?

Tags: 16.04, mount, tmpfs

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.

File `/etc/fstab` contains no references to `/run/user/...`

`mount` prints

```
...
tmpfs on /run/user/115 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1612068k,mode=700,uid=115,gid=124)
tmpfs on /run/user/1002 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1612068k,mode=700,uid=1002,gid=1002)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1612068k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

I need a couple gigabytes more in `/run/user/1002`.

Where do I tune it?

Comment: Try to resize /run using the steps described in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/323071/595510.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. I've got a newer version of OS, no such file.

Comment: Currently I've added a line to `/etc/fstab`. Will study for manuals to check if it is a correct solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can increase it by setting *RuntimeDirectorySize* in /etc/systemd/logind.conf as mentioned here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Profile-sync-daemon#I_need_more_memory_to_accommodate_my_profile.2Fprofiles_in_.2Frun.2Fuser.2Fxxxx._How_can_I_allocate_more.3F

> The standard way of controlling the size of /run/user is the
>   RuntimeDirectorySize directive in /etc/systemd/logind.conf (see the
>   man page for logind.conf for more). By default, 10% of physical memory
>   is used but one can increase it safely. Remember that tmpfs only
>   consumes what is actually used; the number specified here is just a
>   maximum allowed.

From the logind.conf man page:

> RuntimeDirectorySize=
>   Sets the size limit on the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR runtime directory for each user who logs in. Takes a size in bytes, optionally
>   suffixed with the usual K, G, M, and T suffixes, to
>   the base 1024 (IEC). Alternatively, a numerical percentage suffixed by "%" may be specified, which sets the size limit relative
>   to the amount of physical RAM. Defaults to 10%.
>              Note that this size is a safety limit only. As each runtime directory is a tmpfs file system, it will only consume as much memory
>   as is needed.

You will need to log out and in again for the changes to take effect.