# Tpmfs /run 100% used

Tags: server, 18.04, mount, nginx, vps

I have a VPS with Nginx for a wordpress blog and I have a problem I don't know for what reason.

Whenever `tmpfs 99M 20M 79M 21% / run` gets 100% of used my database drops and I need to reboot the server. I'm starting with servers and I don't know what is causing it.

Is there a configuration error?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            465M     0  465M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M   20M   79M  21% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   12G  6.6G  64% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

Dist: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: You seem to reach the limits of your server. 99M is not a lot for /run/ I would expect more like 2Gb when you run a database. Can you increase /run/ yourself? Otherwise I would assume you would need to get a more powerful server.

Comment: @Melebius https://askubuntu.com/questions/855740/how-do-i-increase-size-of-per-user-tmpfs-partition-run-user-id ;) /run/user/0 is 99m too so I assume it will do /run/ by itself